# Kotlin Inner Class can not initiate Session object

Tags: android, kotlin, inner-classes

```
    import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.Color
import android.net.Uri
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toolbar
import java.util.ArrayList
import com.salesrep.auxxa.alliontechnologies.auxxasr.R.id.viewPager

import android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter
import android.util.Log
import com.salesrep.auxxa.alliontechnologies.auxxasr.utillities.Session
import org.json.JSONObject


class NewPaymentActivity : AppCompatActivity(),SummaryFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener,ReceiptDetailsFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener{

    internal lateinit var viewpageradapter: ViewPagerAdapter //Declare PagerAdapter

    private var tabLayout: TabLayout? = null
    var viewPager: ViewPager? = null
    var toolbar: Toolbar? = null
    var myPreference : Session? =null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_payment)
        myPreference= Session(this)
        viewpageradapter= ViewPagerAdapter(supportFragmentManager)

        viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewPager) as ViewPager
        setupViewPager(viewPager!!)

        tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tab_layout) as TabLayout
        tabLayout!!.setupWithViewPager(viewPager)

//      tabLayout!!.setSelectedTabIndicatorColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.t));
        tabLayout!!.setSelectedTabIndicatorHeight(0)




        val headerView = (getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater)
                .inflate(R.layout.custom_tabs_for_payments, null, false)

        val receiptDetails = headerView.findViewById(R.id.tb_receipt_details) as TextView
        val paymentDetails = headerView.findViewById(R.id.tb_payment_details) as TextView
        val invoiceDetails = headerView.findViewById(R.id.tb_invoice_details) as TextView
        val summary = headerView.findViewById(R.id.tb_summary) as TextView

        receiptDetails.setTextColor(resources.getColor(R.color.white))
        val drawable = receiptDetails.getBackground() as GradientDrawable
        drawable.setColor(resources.getColor(R.color.received_payments))

        paymentDetails.setTextColor(resources.getColor(R.color.main))
        val drawablepaymentDetails = paymentDetails.getBackground() as GradientDrawable
        drawablepaymentDetails.setColor(resources.getColor(R.color.white))

        invoiceDetails.setTextColor(resources.getColor(R.color.main))
        val drawableinvoiceDetails = invoiceDetails.getBackground() as GradientDrawable
        drawableinvoiceDetails.setColor(resources.getColor(R.color.white))

        summary.setTextColor(resources.getColor(R.color.main))
        val summarydrawable = summary.getBackground() as GradientDrawable
        summarydrawable.setColor(resources.getColor(R.color.white))

        tabLayout!!.getTabAt(0)!!.setCustomView(receiptDetails)
        tabLayout!!.getTabAt(1)!!.setCustomView(paymentDetails)
        tabLayout!!.getTabAt(2)!!.setCustomView(invoiceDetails)
        tabLayout!!.getTabAt(3)!!.setCustomView(summary)



        tabLayout!!.addOnTabSelectedListener(object : TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener {

            override fun onTabSelected(tab: TabLayout.Tab?) {

                if(tab!!.position==0)
                {
                    Log.e("tab","0")

                    receiptDetails.setTextColor(resources.getColor(R.color.white))
                    val drawable = receiptDetails.getBackground() as GradientDrawable
                    drawable.setColor(resources.getColor(R.color.received_payments))

                    paymentDetails.setTextColor(resources.getColor(R.color.main))
                    val drawablepaymentDetails = paymentDetails.getBackground() as GradientDrawable
                    drawablepaymentDetails.setColor(resources.getColor(R.color.white))

                    invoiceDetails.setTextColor(resources.getColor(R.color.main))
                    val drawableinvoiceDetails = invoiceDetails.getBackground() as GradientDrawable
                    drawableinvoiceDetails.setColor(resources.getColor(R.color.white))

                    summary.setTextColor(resources.getColor(R.color.main))
                    val summarydrawable = summary.getBackground() as GradientDrawable
                    summarydrawable.setColor(resources.getColor(R.color.white))
                }
                else if(tab!!.position==1 && myPreference!!.getReceiptStatus())
                {

                    Log.e("tab","1")
                    Log.e("stataus",myPreference!!.getReceiptStatus().toString())

                    paymentDetails.setTextColor(resources.getColor(R.color.white))
                    val drawable = paymentDetails.getBackground() as GradientDrawable
                    drawable.setColor(resources.getColor(R.color.received_payments))

                    receiptDetails.setTextColor(resources.getColor(R.color.main))
                    val drawablereceiptDetails= receiptDetails.getBackground() as GradientDrawable
                    drawablereceiptDetails.setColor(resources.getColor(R.color.white))

                    invoiceDetails.setTextColor(resources.getColor(R.color.main))
                    val drawableinvoiceDetails = invoiceDetails.getBackground() as GradientDrawable
                    drawableinvoiceDetails.setColor(resources.getColor(R.color.white))

                    summary.setTextColor(resources.getColor(R.color.main))
                    val summarydrawable = summary.getBackground() as GradientDrawable
                    summarydrawable.setColor(resources.getColor(R.color.white))


                }
                else if(tab!!.position==2)
                {
                    Log.e("tab","2")

                    invoiceDetails.setTextColor(resources.getColor(R.color.white))
                    val drawable = invoiceDetails.getBackground() as GradientDrawable
                    drawable.setColor(resources.getColor(R.color.received_payments))

                    receiptDetails.setTextColor(resources.getColor(R.color.main))
                    val drawablereceiptDetails= receiptDetails.getBackground() as GradientDrawable
                    drawablereceiptDetails.setColor(resources.getColor(R.color.white))

                    paymentDetails.setTextColor(resources.getColor(R.color.main))
                    val drawablepaymentDetails = paymentDetails.getBackground() as GradientDrawable
                    drawablepaymentDetails.setColor(resources.getColor(R.color.white))

                    summary.setTextColor(resources.getColor(R.color.main))
                    val summarydrawable = summary.getBackground() as GradientDrawable
                    summarydrawable.setColor(resources.getColor(R.color.white))


                }
                else if(tab!!.position==3)
                {
                    Log.e("tab","3")

                    summary.setTextColor(resources.getColor(R.color.white))
                    val drawable = summary.getBackground() as GradientDrawable
                    drawable.setColor(resources.getColor(R.color.received_payments))

                    receiptDetails.setTextColor(resources.getColor(R.color.main))
                    val drawablereceiptDetails = receiptDetails.getBackground() as GradientDrawable
                    drawablereceiptDetails.setColor(resources.getColor(R.color.white))

                    paymentDetails.setTextColor(resources.getColor(R.color.main))
                    val drawablepaymentDetails = paymentDetails.getBackground() as GradientDrawable
                    drawablepaymentDetails.setColor(resources.getColor(R.color.white))

                    invoiceDetails.setTextColor(resources.getColor(R.color.main))
                    val drawableinvoiceDetails = invoiceDetails.getBackground() as GradientDrawable
                    drawableinvoiceDetails.setColor(resources.getColor(R.color.white))
                }
                else {

                }

            }
            override fun onTabUnselected(tab:TabLayout.Tab?){
            }
            override fun onTabReselected(tab:TabLayout.Tab?) {
            }
        })


    }

    private fun setupViewPager(viewPager: ViewPager) {
        viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(-1);
        val adapter = ViewPagerAdapter(supportFragmentManager)
        viewPager.adapter = adapter



    }

   inner class ViewPagerAdapter(manager: FragmentManager) : FragmentPagerAdapter(manager) {



        override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment? {
            var fragment: Fragment? = null

            if (position == 0 ) {
                Log.e("frag",position.toString())
                fragment = ReceiptDetailsFragment()
            } else if (position == 1 && myPreference!!.getReceiptStatus() ) {
                Log.e("frag",position.toString())
                fragment = PaymentDetailsFragment()
            } else if (position == 2) {
                Log.e("frag",position.toString())
                fragment = InvoiceDetailsFragment()
            } else if (position == 3) {
                Log.e("frag",position.toString())
                fragment = InvoiceDetailsFragment()
            }
            return fragment
        }

        override fun getPageTitle(position: Int): CharSequence {
            return when (position) {
                0 -> "Receipt Details"
                1 -> "Payment Details"
                2 -> "Invocie Details"
                3 -> "Summary"
                else -> throw IllegalArgumentException()
            }
        }

        override fun getCount(): Int {
            return 4
        }
    }

    override fun onFragmentInteraction(jsonObject: JSONObject) {
        //session intialization
        val myPreference = Session(this)
        myPreference.setJsonObject(jsonObject.toString())
        viewPager!!.setCurrentItem(1,true)


    }


    override fun onFragmentInteraction(uri: Uri) {

    }

}

private operator fun Int.invoke(i: Int) {

}
```

> Above I have attched my NewPaymentActivity class.But issue is that I got one null pointer exception once I run this code.I need to use session values inside my inner class.But It seems session initialization pass null value.
>   Inside inner class I used **myPreference!!.getReceiptStatus()** but myPreference value is null.Below I'll attch my log record also.

```
 Process: com.salesrep.auxxa.alliontechnologies.auxxasr, PID: 6082
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Class java.lang.Object.getClass()' on a null object reference
```

Answer (score 1):

```
myPreference!!.getReceiptStatus()
```

avoid using "!!", do always check for nullable,

```
myPreference?.let { it.getReceiptStatus() }
```

use like this, exception will be solved

```
override fun onFragmentInteraction(jsonObject: JSONObject) {
    //session intialization
    val myPreference = Session(this)
    myPreference.setJsonObject(jsonObject.toString())
    viewPager!!.setCurrentItem(1,true)


}
```

here you are assigning the local variable of myPreference, i think u might need to change or assign it to the global one
just remove val from - val myPreference = Session(this)

Comment: Hi, still crash occurs mate.why myPreference get null ?

Comment: I used that Akash.But same crash happened.

Comment: put a debug point  myPreference.setJsonObject() and check whether model gets assigned or not, check whether jsonObject has any data or not

Comment: Akash.It has the value. But the issue is that the myPreference variable inside the inner class gets null.I could not understand it.

Comment: ViewPagerAdapter(manager: FragmentManager, session : Session) try passing it as a variable once

Comment: tested it not the success.

Comment: first of all change the variable name of session model, as it has taken a while to understand me that its a model now let me edit my answer, can u post session model too

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184626/discussion-between-akash-dubey-and-rajitha-perera).

Comment: Hi I solved it. Actually issue it that my fragment getting null.Thank you for the effort.